# Regex Matching file type

Tags: regex, wildcard, pentaho

I've got two files:

```
xxx.qgs
xxx.qgs.cgf
```

Now I need an Regex to find both of them.
I tried several things but cannot make it fetch both. 
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: *"I tried several things.."* Mind posting them here?

Comment: Read about [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) and [optional groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html). And you might need to also have a look at the [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Comment: @CinCout: Too many and none of them got me to solve the problem

Comment: If you don't post whatever you've tried, the question is likely to be closed. That's the reason I asked you to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one :

```
(xxx\.qgs(\.cgf)?)
```

`xxx\.qgs` match exactly xxx.qgs

`(\.cgf)?` match exactly .cfg one or 0 time

Comment: Solved. I changed it to (.*\.qgs(\.cgf)?) to get files. thanks